# Speech to Text word level Confidence does not work for Google API in Python

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I enabled word-level confidence for Google Speech To Text API in Python. But I am not able to get word-level confidence as it always responds "Service is not responding"

```
# setting the config
enable_word_time_offsets = True
enable_automatic_punctuation = True
enable_word_confidence = True
config = {
         "enable_word_time_offsets": enable_word_time_offsets,
         "enable_word_confidence": enable_word_confidence,
         "language_code": self.language,
         "enable_automatic_punctuation": enable_automatic_punctuation}
```

Comment: Try another APIs ;)